# Why is my data only showing up sometimes in CloudKit?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, tuples, cloudkit

I made an app that is supposed to upload a term and an answer from an array of tuples, however, it will only show up sometimes in cloudKit. Sometimes it will upload 3 sets of terms and answers, but then other times it will only upload one set of terms and answers. Is it possible that I am overwriting the Cloudkit data rather than appending it?
Thanks in advance

Heres my code:

```
let term = termTextField.text!
let answer = answerTextField.text!
termAnswer.append((term,answer))
print(termAnswer.self)
let newTA = CKRecord(recordType: "Terms")

newTA["answers"] = answer as CKRecordValue?
var publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
publicData.save(newTA, completionHandler: {(record, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil{
        print("TA Saved")
    }
    else{
        print("Not Saved")
    }
})

newTA["terms"] = term as CKRecordValue?
publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
publicData.save(newTA, completionHandler: {(record, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            print("TA Saved")
        }
        else{
            print("Not Saved")

        }
    })
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, i did not..

Comment: Can you get it to happen on both physical and simulator? Do you always get TA Saved in the console? I would suggest adding `print(error!)` to see if you are getting any rate limiting.